# passing a pointer to an object inside of an NSArray using ARC

Tags: objective-c, pointers, reference, automatic-ref-counting, bridge

I'm converting to ARC, and can't find any way to get rid of this compiler error without breaking the code as well.

I need to pass 2 objects into a selector so I add them both to an array as shown below and send that array to the selector:

```
LWPagerContent* content = nil;
NSArray* args = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:article, [NSValue valueWithPointer:&content], nil];

[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(initArticlePagerContent:) withObject:args waitUntilDone:YES];
```

This method accesses the array, but needs to modify the object at the address referenced in the array. It should initialize the LWPagerContent object as shown, and then that object will be used by the original method that called performSelector.

```
- (void)initArticlePagerContent:(NSArray*)args {
Article* article = [args objectAtIndex:0];

LWPagerContent** contentPtr = [[args objectAtIndex:1] pointerValue];
*contentPtr = [[NSClassFromString([StyleSheet articleContentClass]) alloc] initWithArticle:article];
```

}

This works fine, but when I try to convert to ARC I'm immediately told that `"Implicit conversion of a non-Objective-C type 'void *' to 'LWPagerContent *__strong *' is disallowed with ARC"`. This error occurs on the line that starts with `"LWPagerContent **..."` (2nd to last one shown above). I've tried using `__bridge` and `__autoreleasing` as recommended in other posts, but nothing seems to work. Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are we assuming you can't just change initArticlePagerContent:?

Comment: The name `init...` has special meaning in ARC. Is this really an initializer? If not, don't start its name with `init`.

Comment: Please say more precisely on what line the error occurs and what you've tried.

Comment: Yes we can change initArticlePagerContent but to my understanding if I need to pass multiple objects when performing a selector like this I should be using an Array as I've done, otherwise there would be no way to send both objects together.

Comment: The error occurs on this line:           LWPagerContent** contentPtr = [[args objectAtIndex:1] pointerValue];

Comment: The compiler doesn't know (nor do we) what sort of object you have in `arg[1]`, nor does it know what the method `pointerValue` is.

Comment: Note that passing the address of a slot on the stack between threads is a really bad idea.  In this case, it may work, but the optimizer might move things around on the stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiler doesn't know what to do with your raw pointer. You should explicitly state what kind of memory managing strategy you expect. In you case it can be something like

```
LWPagerContent * __strong *contentPtr = (LWPagerContent * __strong *)[[args objectAtIndex:1] pointerValue];
```

The type is "pointer to a strong pointer to `LWPagerContent`". From now `*contentPtr` will be treated as a strong pointer by ARC.

Comment: Not really;  it "works",but it isn't good design.  The moment you make that call from your secondary thread to the main asynchronous, it'll go boom, for example, or, at the least, require a bunch of refactoring.

Answer (score 7):

Use a block to go to the main thread, eliminating the meta-programming implied by the -performSelector: call.

Then use a callback to set the generated content.

I.e.

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    LWPagerContent *newContent = ... do something ...
    [self setPagerContent:newContent];
});
```

Some notes:

- methods should not be called `init...` unless they are initializers
- pass-by-reference is generally to be avoided
- meta-programming undermines the compiler's ability to do sanity checks.  Avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
NSValue* contentPtrPtr = [args objectAtIndex:1];
LWPagerContent** contentPtr = [contentPtrPtr pointerValue];
```